# Mysql - search in "one to many" table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, one-to-many

I have got table "one to many" with structure "id, user_id, skill". User could have multiple skills, for example "mysql" and "php".

When somebody would like to search user with skills "php" and "mysql" should write in search-form "php mysql".

I made some MYSQL query(condition): `"... WHERE skill LIKE '%php%' AND skill LIKE '%mysql%'"` but it returns nothing.

How can I improve that?

Also I tried something like `"WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', skill) LIKE '%php%' AND CONCAT_WS(' ', skill) LIKE '%mysql%'"`. It's also return nothing.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name
FROM users t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT s.user_id
    FROM skills s
    GROUP BY s.user_id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN s.skill LIKE '%php%' OR
                         s.skill LIKE '%mysql%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 2
) t2
    ON t2.user_id = t1.id
```

The inner query finds users who have both the `PHP` and `MySQL` skill, and this result is then used to filter the `users` table to return only the names who match this requirement.

I assume in my query that a given skill will appear once and only once for a given user.  If the same skill could appear multiple times for the same user, the query will need to be slightly modified.

## SQLFiddle

**Update:**

If your `skills` table might have the same skill listed for a given user multiple times, you can ignore these duplicate entries by using `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name
FROM users t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT s.user_id
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, skill FROM skills) s
    GROUP BY s.user_id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN s.skill LIKE '%php%' OR s.skill LIKE '%mysql%' 
               OR s.skill LIKE '%javascript%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 3
) t2
    ON t2.user_id = t1.id
```

Note in the Fiddle below that Mark does *not* appear in the result set, as although he has PHP as a skill listed twice, he does not have either MySQL or JavaScript.

## SQLFiddle

Comment: It's also return nothing. Please look here, I just made SQL schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5008a6/1

Comment: @Ridd I think you want to use the `OR`, not `AND` operator.  Check my update.

Comment: It's working, great! Thank you. It's more complicated but I hope it's also efficient and will not kill my db :) Thanks again.

Comment: What about repeated skills? Could you show me what I need to change in your query? For example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/500da6/2

Comment: @Ridd Have a look at my updated answer.  To cover the case where skills may be repeated you can use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates from the `skills` table.

Comment: If you want to match PHP anywhere in the string, use `WHERE skill LIKE '%php%'`.

Answer (score 0):

A REGEXP might be more efficient, but you'd have to benchmark it to be sure, e.g.

```
SELECT * from table where field REGEXP 'php|mysql';
```

[For Ref.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Comment: This will give php or mysql rite? and we need php and mysql

Comment: This will perform like '%keyword%' operation.
ex: I have db with user table and i want to search based on email id.
SELECT * from users where username REGEXP 'bhavin|kenny';
But i have value in column with "bhavin@tech" and "kenny@tech"

Comment: But this is an OR statement and not an AND statement rite?